# Replace hex in binary file using sfk

Tags: replace, hex

I want to replace a few bytes (256) in a binary file with a different value (same length).

like:

`112233445566....FF` (256 bytes in total)

and want to replace them by for example:

`FFEEDDCCDDBB....00` (256 bytes)

my problem is that 256 bytes of replacement (2 times) seem to be to large for the command line. So is this possible with a SFK script file ?

Have no idea how to do this.

The complete 256 bytes block is only 1 time in the source file.

Any ideas ?

Thanks, Heiko

Comment: provide a code example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok, found a solution after about 1 million tests by myself ;-)
How do i post my code to keep formating ?

Comment: note that you can answer your own question by yourself in order to help other SO users that got a similar problem

Comment: When i post my batch code i get all in one line ;-) So how to put it here "formated" ?

Comment: if you got it formatted in your editor, your paste will be formatted here just like in your editor. then mark your code and click the `Code Sample` button which looks like `{}`

Comment: Don't know - my script always shown as 1 line. anyway - removed the batch stuff so the basic thing is to write the replace command in a batch script because there seem to be no limit for the number of characters.

Command to replace is:

sfk replace  %1 -firsthit -yes -bin "/112233445566/AABBCCDDEEFF/"

I shrinked to a few bytes of hex but my real replace string is 256 bytes.

Comment: no, you need to answer yourself - scroll down and post it as an answer and then you can also accept your own answer after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok. I made a comment instead of a new posting - thanx.

Code:

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto usage
echo.
echo Patch file
pause

// create a backup of the original file before doing the patch
copy %1 %1.bak

// patching the file using Swiss File Knife
sfk replace  %1 -firsthit -yes -bin "/112233445566/AABBCCDDEEFF/"
echo.
goto :eof

:usage
@echo Usage: %0 ^<Filename^>
exit /B 1
```